# how to delete a specific file from specific folder in Ubuntu 16.04 using Terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, zip

I want to delete a zip file using terminal but i dont know what the command is for that purpose in Ubuntu.

**fileName**: android-studio-ide-162.3871768-linux.zip   
**location**: /home/raza/Downloads

this is the file i want to delete form the location mention above.

Comment: `rm` is for remove file if i recall correctly, google knows that btw. Execute this in the terminal: `rm /home/raza/Downloads/android-studio-ide-162.3871768-linux.zip`

Comment: This helped me. Worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities:

```
$ rm  /home/raza/Downloads/android-studio-ide-162.3871768-linux.zip
```

or:

```
$ unlink /home/raza/Downloads/android-studio-ide-162.3871768-linux.zip
```

In `bash` and similar shells you can also used `~raza` to denote `/home/raza` so it would be:

```
$ rm  ~raza/Downloads/android-studio-ide-162.3871768-linux.zip
```

or:

```
$ unlink  ~raza/Downloads/android-studio-ide-162.3871768-linux.zip
```

Or if you are currently logged in as user `raza` you can just use `~` alone:

```
$ rm  ~/Downloads/android-studio-ide-162.3871768-linux.zip
```

or:

```
$ unlink  ~/Downloads/android-studio-ide-162.3871768-linux.zip
```

Comment: Worked for me.$ rm  /home/raza/Downloads/android-studio-ide-162.3871768-linux.zip

Comment: OK. If you like this answer please mark it accepted so that other users know it's solved.

Comment: How is unlink different from rm?

Comment: Good question - see this answer on `sereverfault`: https://serverfault.com/questions/38816/what-is-the-difference-between-unlink-and-rm

Answer (score 0):

you need to use: `rm`

`-i` prompt before every removal
`-f`ignore nonexistent files and arguments
`-r`remove directories and their contents recursively

---

remove all file and all directory ( very dangerous ):  `rm -fr *`
remove all file: `rm -f *`
remove all directory: `rm -r *`
remove every thing except `.sh` file: `rm -f !(*.sh)`
remove a special file: `rm -f your-path`